# SerialPort.WriteLine(string) has some invalid arguments and cannot convert argument to string

Tags: c#, string, serial-port, arguments

I get the two following errors with the code below on the same line `port.WriteLine(gcode);`, do I need to create a for loop for each item of the list?

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.WriteLine(string)' has some invalid arguments
>
> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'string'

code:

```
//Fields
SerialPort port;
string myReceivedLines;

protected override void SolveInstance(IGH_DataAccess DA)
{
    List<string> gcode = new List<string>();
    DA.GetDataList(0, gcode);

    if (!DA.GetDataList(0, gcode)) 
        return;

    port = new SerialPort(selectedportname, selectedbaudrate, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One); 
    port.DtrEnable = true;  
    port.Open();            
    port.DataReceived += this.portdatareceived;

    if (gcode == null)
    {
        AddRuntimeMessage(GH_RuntimeMessageLevel.Warning, "Specify a valid GCode");
        return;
    }

    if (connecttodevice == true)
    {
        DA.SetDataList(0, myReceivedLines);
    }

    if (sendtoprint == true)
    {
        port.WriteLine(gcode);
    }
}

private void portdatareceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    myReceivedLines = port.ReadExisting();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach(string s in gcode)
{
    port.WriteLine(s);
}
```

SerialPort knows how to write string, but there is no SerialPort method accepting `List<string>`.

Edit.
Try this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(string s in gcode)
{
    sb.Append(s)
} 
port.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @AlexFarber, the problem with the for each loop in this case is that it outputs each characters on separate line, is there a way to keep sentences on one line?

Comment: Use SerialPort.Write - it doesn't append new line.

Comment: Hi Alex, i tried SerialPort.Write with the same loop but it didn't change the results unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (sendtoprint == true)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < gcode.Count(); i++)
   {
      port.WriteLine(gcode[i]);
   }
}
```

You can solve it as you say